# Friendly backpacker place on Lake Victoria?

Tags: accommodation, backpacking, uganda

After a week of work in Kampala I am considering spending this Christmas on one of the Lake Victoria islands. I have read nice things about [Banda Island](http://www.traveluganda.co.ug/banda-island/), and I am considering this place. [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g480251-d2414575-Reviews-Banda_Island-Ssese_Islands.html) has several positive reviews. Is it still up and running? Any recent experiences?

Last year in February I stayed at the Ssese Islands Beach hotel with a colleague. Nice place, but this time I would like to venture to slightly a more exotic place than just 500 meters away form the ferry port.

Does anyone have relevant information about this place, or other relevant places/lodges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Friends of friends stayed on Banda island this year, so it's still up and running. I was told they liked it.

Did you consider going up to Jinja? I personally like Eden Rock; it's affordable and right next to the party venue that is Nile River Explorers, meaning you can choose to party and choose to take it easy without having to go far.
Alternatively, I hear good things about the [Hairy Lemon](http://hairylemonuganda.com/) as well, which *is* on an island.

Comment: We, me and my wife, are also considering going to Jinja. Your suggestions are therefore relevant. Eden Rock sounds like a nice place.

Comment: Jinja is really the place.